# MySQL Storing Reports

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am looking for a way to store auto-generated reports. There are about 10-15 columns and 100-3000 rows depending on the report but each report is consistent in column count.
I am looking for a way to organise and store these reports into a large group without creating an entire new database and 1000s of tables to store each indervidual report.

The reports need to be queryable so they can be subdivided by team/area/person etc as each report can be a combination of 3-4 different sub-reports depending on how you split/sort the data.

I am using Python to collect and sort the data from the database so using MariaDB/MySQL would be preferred but im happy to use something else if there is a pre-exising connection libary for it.

To sum up i need something similar to a excel spreadsheet with each table being a sheet and sheet name being the date it was generated so i can select by the date generated.

Comment: It sounds like you need a table with some columns (id *,report_id, date_generated, other_data...)

Answer (score 0):

Think through the goals.

- Is this a legal issue -- you need to produce an unalterable report as something "official".  A la a non-editable .pdf?
- (at the opposite extreme) Be able to generate (or regenerate) any report for any timeframe.
- Is performance an issue?  (Either perceived or real)

I like to build and maintain Summary Table(s) for any "Data Warehouse" application.  And build "reports" that take as a parameter a date range and a small number of other things.  And have the report generation so fast that it does not matter if multiple people are pulling reports at random times.

15 columns and 3000 rows is usually excessive.  If pulling a report is trivial enough, it can be less 'massive'; just get the parts you want, without such bulk.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables